# Using a constant in an AngularJS file

Tags: angularjs

I'd need to use a constant to reference an URL address in my AngularJS Controller. Based on the examples I have found so far I have coded (small snippet):

```
var app = angular.module("customerManagement", []).constant('SERVER_URL','http://localhost:8080/customers');

app.controller("customerManagementController", function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.customers = [];
$scope.form = {
  id: -1,
  name: "",
  surname: ""
};
//Now load the data from server
_refreshPageData();
//HTTP POST/PUT methods for add/edit customers
$scope.update = function () {
  var method = "";
  var url = "";
  var data = {};
  if ($scope.form.id == -1) {
    //Id is absent so add customers - POST operation
    method = "POST";
    url = SERVER_URL;
    data.name = $scope.form.name;
    data.surname = $scope.form.surname;
  }
```

But it does not seem to work. In the console I can see:

```
Error: SERVER_URL is not defined
```

What's wrong with my constant definition?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to inject it in your controller:

```
app.controller("customerManagementController", function ($scope, $http, 
SERVER_URL) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however I get a "SyntaxError: missing formal parameter" when I inject it into the Controller.

Comment: Got it working with: `app.controller("customerManagementController",  function ($scope, $http, SERVER_URL) {`

Comment: Ok, I will edit again. This was my first answer before adding the quotes. Good job